# playing YouTube video in PIP mode like WhatsApp

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, youtubeplayer, android-picture-in-picture

I am currently wokring in project where I've to implement a feature (PiP mode)in which if a user clicks on the youtube link, it should play in PIP mode like WhatsApp. I am using Youtube Android Player API. I'm able to put the video in PiP mode but I'm getting this Error from Youtube Payer API

> E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Embed config is not supported in RemoteEmbeddedPlayer.

So does anyone tried or have any idea why it's happening ? & yes there's no overlay, padding, margin & any kind views over my YoutubePlayerView

Comment: please edit your question and incldue your code.

Comment: Do you find any solution to this?

Comment: No Not yet ! tried many things but nothing is working so far till now

Comment: Yeah... facing the same issue

Comment: Are you found the solution? I've tired past 3 days but still not yet get the solution.